# .NET Core Web App Restarting

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a .NET core web app (console) hosted in IIS on a Windows machine. In the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` I have a line of code which sends me an email so that I know when the service is restarted.  When a new release is being deployed, I get that email, understandably.  But I also receive that email at random times when there was no apparent restart of the machine, the app, or of any IIS component.  Would there be any other thing which would cause it to restart?  I'm not sure why this is happening.

Thanks,

Comment: Its by design and how IIS manages the app pool. It will stop idle application or when it requires the resources for something else. While increasing the time you should always expect IIS to stop or restart your application at any given time for any given reason (even when its set to managed). Either run a scheduler to send a request regularly, change the timeout time (delays it doesn't prevent it)

Answer (score 0):

IIS has a lot of settings for AppPool reset, like e.g. at given time, etc. You can check the advanced settings of your application pool that is set up to run your program and see if there is anything suspicious. It might be some inactivity timeout e.g.

Answer (score 0):

There is also IDLE timeout and action in application pool advanced settings. If the action is terminate process IIS service will be restarted.